# Folder dialog selecting the preceding folder

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to use a file dialog to select a folder that will be used later on in the code. The following is being used as a part of a Userform that calls several other macros and takes various other user inputs as strings.

What this macro is supposed to do (later on in the code) is export a file to a folder that the user specifies with this `fldrpicker` dialog. The problem is this: The file exports to the folder *before* the one I want, and I can't figure out why.

```
`Public FilePath as String
Private Sub folderpicker_click() 'A field in the UserForm
Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled
    Dim fldr As FileDialog, sItem As String
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = "\\user\Desktop\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\"
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
FilePath = fldr.InitialFileName
NextCode:
    GetFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
DestinationFolder.Value = sItem
End Sub
`
```

With this code, the file will save in `Folder2` and not `Folder3` like it I need it to. I've tried to troubleshoot with a temporary sub that uses `msgbox(FilePath)` right after this runs, but it tells me that `FilePath` is `\\user\Desktop\Folder1\Folder2\` so I don't think the error is exporting it (that's why I haven't included that bit of code).

Comment: sItem is defined after error handline for GoTo NextCode; if the NextCode is determining sItem, then the filepath is getting overwritten, no?  GetFolder = sItem in NextCode.  would need to be sItem = GetFolder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what is happening is because you are using FilePath = fldr.InitialFileName, which is in essence the original folder selected in the dialogue, if you change your code to this it should work as expected:

```
Sub foo()
Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled
    Dim fldr As FileDialog, sItem As String
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = "\\user\Desktop\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\"
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
FilePath = sItem
NextCode:
    GetFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
DestinationFolder.Value = sItem
End Sub
```

Comment: This works. Thank you! I knew it had to be something simple.